# What is the ratio of the areas of the two squares?

Tags: geometry

A circle with radius $r=1$ has a square inscribed in it. There is another square inserted in the segment between the large square and the perifery of the circle, with one side tangent to the large square and two points touching the edge of the circle. I figured that the sides depicted are $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ thus giving the area side of the large square to $\sqrt{2}.$ However in order to find the area of the small square, I need to find the length $x$.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Let C be the center point, A the middle of bottom side of the smaller square and B the lower right hand corner of the smaller square.

Length of CA is $x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Length of AB is $\frac{x}{2}$.

CB is a radius of the circle and also the hypotenuse of the right triangle CAB.

So we have

$1 = \sqrt{(x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2 + (\frac{x}{2})^2 }$

Solving for x, and taking the positive root, you have:

$x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{5}$